# How to automatically load Entities with @ManyToMany relations in Java

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I'm trying to learn how to create a Java Enterprise application (currently using EclipseLink), in there I have a `User` entity that has a `@ManyToMany` relationship with a `Card` entity, However when the users gets loaded from the database, the cards atribute does not get populated automatically as I would expect.

Here is my User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USR")
public class User extends Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "CPF", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String cpf;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", length = 20, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "BDAY")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date bDay;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", length = 100, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Card> cards;

    public User() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Here is my Card entity:

```
@Entity
public class Card implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String number;

    @Column(name = "EXP_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date expDate;

    @Column(name = "VALIDATOR")
    private int validator;

    @Transient
    private String endsWith;

    public Card() {
    }
}
```

So when my `servlet` is instantiated I load a user from the database like so `userBean.setUser(userFactoryEJB.find(2));` and it works fine, I'm able to access the user email, bday, username, etc. However when I try to get the user cards I get the following message `{IndirectList: not instantiated}`. Before one might ask, I did try to initialize the list on the User constructor and the same message appears.

What I would expect is that the User gets loaded from DB with all their cards already loaded in the card attribute.

Comment: What do you mean by try to access it? The message you posted isn't an error.  Are you calling getCards and iterating over the List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default fetch type for a collection-valued relationship is lazy. When a transaction is committed all loaded entities to become detached and you cannot access to lazy load entities.

I think that you retrieve the user in another transaction.

please check your TransactionAttribute annotation.

some of the possible solutions are:

1)do you use userFactoryEJB in a CDI bean or in another session bean? you must call userFactoryEJB from another session bean or use @Transactional on your CDI bean.

2)change the fetch type to eager.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Card> cards;
```

3)define another find method and call getcrads() method before returning the user